# Delete all Rows that couldn't find a JOIN?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, inner-join

I have this query:

```
SELECT Auctions.ID 
FROM Auctions
INNER JOIN Products ON Auctions.ProductID = Products.ID
```

Now as far as i know if i have an auction:

```
ID | ProductID
1  |   12
```

And the ProductID 12 is not on the Products table, so the row wont be selected.

If i am right, i want to delete all the rows that didn't found the Product ID on the Products table. (the products that couldn't find a JOIN)

How can i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DELETE Auctions WHERE ProductId NOT IN(SELECT ProductId FROM Products)
```

Of course, after you do this, do yourself a favor and create a Relationship from `Auctions.ProductId` to `Products.ProductId` if you don't want to do this again.

Comment: Hey, can you explain me more about the relationship ?
Everytime i INSERT an auction i use a valid product ID for sure.
but my problam is when a product is deleted after an auction has been created.
Will relationship solve it ?

Comment: If your desire is to have a delete in product force the delete in auctions, look at setting the on cascade delete action when you create the foreign key http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933119(v=sql.80).aspx

Answer (score 5):

```
DELETE FROM a
    FROM Auctions a
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM Products p WHERE p.ID = a.ProductID)
```

Comment: how dissimilar is my answer from yours? Not saying yours doesn't work, just curious.

Comment: @hunter: If the column allows nulls, the NOT EXISTS should perform better. If the column is non-nullable, our answers should perform identically. See [this article](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/02/18/not-exists-vs-not-in/) for details.

Comment: ProductID is never null, always int.
So i think i will use hunter's answer.
+1 for the help :)

Answer (score 3):

A slightly different take on the above answers.  The first shows what auctions have no corresponding product, second actually purges them.  First may be helpful in case there is a pattern of missing products.

```
-- This query identifies everything that is in
-- Auctions that doesn't have a match in Product
SELECT
    A.*
FROM
    Auctions A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        Products P 
        ON A.ProductID = P.ID
WHERE
    P.ProductID IS NULL


-- This query deletes everything that is in
-- Auctions that doesn't have a match in Product
DELETE
    A
FROM
    Auctions A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        Products P 
        ON A.ProductID = P.ID
WHERE
    P.ProductID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM Auctions WHERE ProductId NOT IN (SELECT ProductId FROM Products)
```